# Obtaining coordinates of a ggplot figure

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there a way to obtain the `x` and `y` coordinates of each facet in `R` `ggplot`'s `facet_wrap` figure?

Using the [ggplot's facet_wrap example](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/facet_wrap.html)

```
p <- qplot(displ, hwy, data = mpg)
p + facet_wrap(~ cyl)
```

How can I obtain the `x` and `y` coordinates of each facet of `p` so I can add text or an inset plot to each facet?

Comment: have a look at `ggplot_build(p)`

Comment: You can add text to facets without knowing the coordinates with `geom_text()` or `annotate()`.